# How to convert any image to CV_32FC1

Tags: opencv

I want to convert any image I use as input to CV_32FC1 type. My code is below:

```
char fname[MAX_PATH];
while (openFileDlg(fname))
{
    Mat img = imread(fname, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

    Mat src(img.rows, img.cols, CV_32FC1);
    Mat dst(img.rows, img.cols, CV_32FC1);

    if (img.type() == 0)
    {
        img.convertTo(img, CV_32FC1, 1.0f / 255.0f);
        src = img.clone();
    }
    else
    {
        img.convertTo(img, CV_32FC1);

    }

    std::cout << img.type() << ' ' << src.type();
}
```

For grayscale images it works, but when I use a color image, the conversion doesn't work. For example: for CV_32FC1 the value is 5. When I upload a color image it gives me the value 16, and after conversion is 21. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you want to convert a color image (3 channels) to a _single channel_ image?

Comment: @ZdaR could you possibly take a look at this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195884/opencv-pyrmeanshiftfilter-in-processing-problems-with-matrix>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see inconsistent results for Gray and RGB images to the difference in channel numbers in both cases, 32FC1 can be broken down as:

> - 32F - 32 bit floating value
> - C1 - Single channel

But RGB image or BGRA images have 3, 4 channels respectively, so we can't use C1 for them, hence we need to use 32FC3 for 3-channel image and 32FC4 for 4-channel image.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: Happy to help, Best of Luck :)