# OpenCV pyrMeanShiftFilter in Processing--problems with matrix

Tags: java, opencv, matrix, processing, pixel

I'm trying to use the Mean Shift Function from OpenCV inside a program called Processing, which is a language based on Java. So far, I know that the function requires two mat and two double, [ pyrMeanShiftFiltering( Mat, Mat, Double, Double) ] and the mat needs to be 8 bits and 3 channels. But, when I run it, it only seems to work for the upper 3/4 th of the image and cuts out the rest.

Does anyone know how to get this function to run on the whole image?

sample image: [cat.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsoeg.jpg)

```
import gab.opencv.*;
import java.nio.*;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Core; 

OpenCV opencv;
Imgproc imgproc;

PImage canny;
PImage src, out;
Mat one, two;
double a = 20.0;
double b = 10.0;

void setup() {
  src = loadImage("cat.jpg");
  size( 429, 360);

  System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);  
  one = new Mat( width, height, CvType.CV_8UC3);
  two = new Mat( width, height, CvType.CV_8UC3);

  one = toMat(src);
  imgproc.pyrMeanShiftFiltering( one, two, a, b);
  out = toPImage(two); 
}

void draw() {
  image(out, 0, 0, width, height);
}

Mat toMat(PImage image) {  
  int w = image.width;  
  int h = image.height;  
  Mat mat = new Mat(h, w, CvType.CV_8UC3);  
  byte[] data8 = new byte[w*h*4];  
  int[] data32 = new int[w*h];  
  arrayCopy(image.pixels, data32);  
  ByteBuffer bBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(w*h*4);  
  IntBuffer iBuf = bBuf.asIntBuffer();  
  iBuf.put(data32);  
  bBuf.get(data8);  
  mat.put(0, 0, data8);  
  return mat;
}  

 PImage toPImage(Mat mat) { 
  int w = mat.width(); 
  int h = mat.height(); 
  PImage image = createImage(w, h, ARGB); 
  byte[] data8 = new byte[w*h*4]; 
  int[] data32 = new int[w*h]; 
  mat.get(0, 0, data8); 
  ByteBuffer.wrap(data8).asIntBuffer().get(data32); 
  arrayCopy(data32, image.pixels); 
  return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using rows where the columns should be and columns where the rows should be. Check the [Mat documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#Mat(int,%20int,%20int)) for more information.

so, whenever you have this:

```
new Mat( width, height, CvType.CV_8UC3);
```

invert the order

```
new Mat( height, width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
```

Also, I notice that you have a 4 channel images (ARGB) and the toMat function also have 4 channels, but you create a Mat with only 3 `CV_8UC3`, you should use 4 `CV_8UC4` (not sure in java), and beware, normally opencv uses is `BGRA` !! so you may need to mix the channels correctly.

I hope this helps you

Comment: When I invert the order, the image is distorted and still cut off at the bottom. 

For the channels, the function requires a 8 bit and 3 channel and gives me an error if I use 4. Do you know how I could change the toMat function so they have three channels?

Comment: @Qwerty the easiest way (not necessarily the most efficient) would be to use the functions [split](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Core.html#split) and [merge](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Core.html#merge) or [mixChannels](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Core.html#mixChannels). Split will give you each channel as a mat and then join or mix channels can create a 3 channel mat with the ones you want. About the  width and height it should be change everywhere