# Converting JPEG into Mat (8 bits and 3 channels) --- Buffer Overflow Exception

Tags: java, opencv, processing, buffer-overflow, mat

I'm trying to use a filter function from OpenCV in Processing, but before I do, I have to convert my image into a mat that is 8 bits and 3 channels. But whenever I run it, I keep running into a "Buffer Overflow Exception," and I can't figure out why I get that error and how to get the conversion to work.

```
import gab.opencv.*;
import java.nio.*;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Core; 
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage; 
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt; 

OpenCV opencv;
Imgproc imgproc;

PImage src, out;
PImage before, snap;
Mat one, two;
double a = 35.0;
double b = 20.0;

void setup() {
   src = loadImage("cat.jpg");
   size( 429, 360);

  System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);  
  one = new Mat( width, height, CvType.CV_8UC3);
  two = new Mat( width, height, CvType.CV_8UC3);

  one = toMat(src);
  imgproc.pyrMeanShiftFiltering( one, two, a, b);
  out = toPImage(two);
}

void draw() {
  image(out, 0, 0, width, height);
}

Mat toMat(PImage image) {  
  int w = image.width;  
  int h = image.height;  
  Mat mat = new Mat(h, w, CvType.CV_8UC3);  
  byte[] data8 = new byte[w*h*3];  
  int[] data32 = new int[w*h];  
  arrayCopy(image.pixels, data32);  
  ByteBuffer bBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(w*h*3);  
  IntBuffer iBuf = bBuf.asIntBuffer();  
  iBuf.put(data32); // ERROR -- BufferOverflowException 
  bBuf.get(data8);  
  mat.put(0, 0, data8);  
  return mat;
}  

PImage toPImage(Mat mat) { 
  int w = mat.width(); 
  int h = mat.height(); 
  PImage image = createImage(w, h, RGB); 
  byte[] data8 = new byte[w*h*3]; 
  int[] data32 = new int[w*h]; 
  mat.get(0, 0, data8); 
  ByteBuffer.wrap(data8).asIntBuffer().get(data32); 
  arrayCopy(data32, image.pixels); 
 }
```

Comment: It's because of your `byte[]` Java doesn't have unsigned primitives, so a `byte` in Java ranges from -128-127 not 0-255

Comment: you put a 32 bit data in a 8 x 3 bit data ? my math tells me that is wrong (32 in 24).... try `w*h*4` instead of `w*h*3` :) in the bBuf creation

Comment: @api55 if I change it to four I run into this problem <<<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195884/opencv-pyrmeanshiftfilter-in-processing-problems-with-matrix>>>