# Converting Images to Mat and back

Tags: java, image, opencv, mat, channel

I'm trying to convert my image into mat that is 8 bits and 3 channels and later on back into a image in OpenCV. But my code doesn't seem to be working.

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

```
Mat toMat(PImage image) {  
  int w = image.width;  
  int h = image.height;  
  Mat mat = new Mat(h, w, CvType.CV_8UC3);  
  byte[] data8 = new byte[w*h*4];  
  int[] data32 = new int[w*h];  
  arrayCopy(image.pixels, data32);  
  ByteBuffer bBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(w*h*4);  
  IntBuffer iBuf = bBuf.asIntBuffer();  
  iBuf.put(data32);  
  bBuf.get(data8);  
  mat.put(0, 0, data8);  
  return mat;
}  

PImage toPImage(Mat mat) { 
  int w = mat.width(); 
  int h = mat.height(); 
  PImage image = createImage(h, w, RGB); 
  byte[] data8 = new byte[w*h*4]; 
  int[] data32 = new int[w*h]; 
  mat.get(0, 0, data8); 
  ByteBuffer.wrap(data8).asIntBuffer().get(data32); 
  arrayCopy(data32, image.pixels); 
  return image;
}
```

Comment: The data is 4-channel but you initiate the Mat as 8UC3 instead of 8UC4. What error do you get?

Comment: It doesn't show me any error. It just works on the top part of the image and not the bottom. Do you know how I could change the data into a 3-channel?

Comment: I'm using this code to use the pyrMeanShiftFiltering function which requires two mat and two double. I was having problems with this code. Could you possibly take a look at this ?<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195884/opencv-pyrmeanshiftfilter-in-processing-problems-with-matrix>

Comment: Did you do as the answer suggested, if it is working only on the top-part and not the bottom, that is the solution I can think of too. If you want to change the data to 3-channel, just create it with 3 channels or once you have a Mat you can use cvtColor

Comment: If I change it to 8UC4, I get an error saying that it has to be 8UC3, and if I flip the width and height, the image is still cut off... Could you help me with creating it with 3 channels? I don't quite understand how to do so.